# loop get parent html value if not first level

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<ul>

<li>
    <a class="level" title="" href="">A</a>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a class="level" title="" href="">AA</a>
            <ul>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a class="level" title="" href="">AB</a>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a class="level" title="" href="">ABA</a>
                    <ul>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a class="level" title="" href="">AC</a>
            <ul>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li>
    <a class="level" title="" href="">B</a>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a class="level" title="" href="">BA</a>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a class="level" title="" href="">BAA</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a class="level" title="" href="">BAAA</a>
                            <ul>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a class="level" title="" href="">BAAB</a>
                            <ul>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a class="level" title="" href="">BB</a>
            <ul>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a class="level" title="" href="">BC</a>
            <ul>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>

</ul>
```

how get html value of parent element with jquery when a.level click

```
AA click  result =  A/AA
AB click    "       A/AB

ABA click  result =  A/AB/ABA
AC click    "        A/AC

BA click  result =  B/BA
BAA click    "      B/BA/BAA

BAAB click   "      B/BA/BAA/BAAB
```

with infinite ul li level

```
$('a.level').click(function(){
  //
  return(false);
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The element hierarchy in your markup makes it a little complicated, but you can walk up the `<ul>` ancestor chain with [parents()](http://api.jquery.com/parents/) and fetch the anchor elements you're interested in with [prev()](http://api.jquery.com/prev/).

From there, you can [map()](http://api.jquery.com/map/) the text content of these elements and [join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) the resulting array into an absolute path:

```
$("a.level").click(function() {
    alert($(this).parents("ul").prev("a.level").add(this).map(function() {
        return $(this).text();
    }).get().join("/"));
});
```

You can see this solution in action in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vvtbr/).

Comment: thank you and thank so much for demo action link. this is what i'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a.level').click(function(){
  $(this).parents("a.level");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a.level').click(function(){
  var tempString = '';
  for(var i=0;i<$(this).parents('.level').length;i++){
      tempString += $(this).parents('.level').get(i).text + "/";
  }
  tempString += $(this).text;
  alert(tempString);
}
```